# CAML query items in increments

Tags: c#, sharepoint, asmx, caml

I currently have a sharepoint2010 list that contains roughly 200,000 records.

I want to get each record, tweak it, massage it, and store it in a SQL table.

As of now, I am using the sharepoint 2010 web service method `GetListItems` like so...

```
System.Xml.XmlNode nodeListItems = client.GetListItems("guid", "", query, viewFields, RowNumber, queryOptions, null);
```

querying 200000 records is too much to query at once. How can I get around this? The `GetListItems` method takes CAML query parameters.

Is there a way to do this in increments, like say 5000 records at a time? How would one structure the CAML query to do that?

Unless someone has a better way of accomplishing this altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, you can paginate the results.  The fifth parameter is the page size, you have it set via `RowNumber`.  Set it to 5000 if you want pages of size 5000.

Details on accessing subsequent pages can be seen from the [documentation for the GetListItems method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

> The GetListItems method supports server-side paging. The XML data
>   returned by this method includes a ListItemCollectionPositionNext
>   attribute inside the rs:Data element that contains the information to
>   support paging. This string contains data for the fields in the sort
>   and for other items needed for paging. You should consider this string
>   internal and not to be modified; modifying it can produce unexpected
>   results. The following example shows the form of this return value
>   when paging is supported.
>
> ```
> <rs:Data ListItemCollectionPositionNext=" 
> Paged=TRUE&p_ID=100&View=
>       %7bC68F4A6A%2d9AFD%2d406C%2dB624%2d2CF8D729901E%7d&PageFirstRow=
>       101" Count=1000 >
>    <z:row ows_FirstName="Nancy" ows_LastName="Name" ….. />
>    ...
> </rs:Data>
> ```
>
> To get the next page of data, the queryOption parameter is used, as
>   shown in the following example.
>
> ```
> <QueryOptions>
>   <Paging ListItemCollectionPositionNext=" 
>     Paged=TRUE&p_ID=100&View=
>     %7bC68F4A6A%2d9AFD%2d406C%2dB624%2d2CF8D729901E%7d&PageFirstRow=
>    101" />
> </QueryOptions>
> ```

So all you need to do is grab the data in that attribute from each page's result set and add it to the query to get the next page.